# Makefile: source files in a particular directory

Tags: makefile

What do I need to do if I want to compile several files (e.g. **a.f90**, **b.f90**, **c.f90**) in a given directory (say, **MYDIR**)?

My Makefile code is something like:

```
CC=gfortran
CFLAG=-g
HOME=MYDIR
SRC=$(HOME)/(a.f90,b.f90,c.f90)
OBJ=$(SRC:,=.o)
EXE=test.x
%.o: %.f90
        $(CC) $(CFLAG) -c -o $@ $<
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAG)
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

I think, the **4-th** line is not correct. So what could be the replacement?

Another thought: Can I use a *wildcard* if I want to compile all **.f90** file inside **MYDIR**?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do it.  You can do something like:

```
SRC = $(addprefix $(HOME)/,a.f90 b.f90 c.f90)
```

Also your assignment of OBJ is wrong; there's no comma needed after the colon.

Yes you can use wildcard if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I wanted to use `wildcard` function. But if I use `addprefix` then I can just write `$(addprefix $(HOME)/,*.f90)` in my Makefile code. 

Regarding assigning OBJ, I experience *No rule to make target* error message if I do not use a space or comma after the colon.